# SQL Group sum Date diff

Tags: date, ms-access

First of all I am not to knowledgeable with SQL statements, I can do a basic one but doing a group, sum and datediff has me all confused for what i am trying to do.

what I am tying to accomplish is break down my entries into the database as follows  by state, sum of fuel bought for truck, trailer and def fuel, total amount spent, and be able to do it per month or by quarter per truck.
I know one would be like this for basic but for a more complicated SQL statement I am totally lost over it.
A Basic Statement would be like this

```
TNumber = Request.Cookies("Truck_Number")
MySQL= "SELECT * FROM Fueling_Information WHERE Truck_Number = TNumber"
```

But To do a group covering all the fields in the table to be able to do what I would like would be a lot more complicated and that is where I am over my head in trying to figure it out.
like Below adding all transactions for each state, and totaling the amounts by truck number and by Month or Quarterly.

```
State       Truck Fuel           Trailer Fuel   Total Price
AL            101.05                  25.667        900.57
IL            150.95                  12.650       1075.30
MS             75.25                  10.500        210.50
```

The statement that access shows in its design built groups the transactions in groups by state but it has multiple same states   Like:

```
State       Truck Fuel            Trailer Fuel   Total Price
AL            101.05                  25.667        900.57
AL            271.05                  20.167        600.00
IL            150.95                  12.650       1075.30
MS             75.25                  10.500        210.50
MS             75.25                  10.500        210.50
MS             75.25                  10.500        210.50
```

Which is not what I am really wanting because it shows the states where multiple purchases are done several times instead of 1 state and sums of each column based off month or quarter selected and segregated by `truck_number = to TNumber`

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
   Fueling_Information.ID, 
   Fueling_Information.Fuel_Location_Name, 
   Fueling_Information.Fuel_Price_DEF, 
   Format$([Fueling_Information].[Fuel_Date_Added],'mmmm yyyy')
      AS [Fuel_Date_Added By Month], 
   Fueling_Information.Fuel_Truck_Number, 
   Fueling_Information.Fuel_Trailer_Number,
   Fueling_Information.Fuel_City,
   Fueling_Information.Fuel_State,    
   Fueling_Information.Fuel_Station_Number,
   Fueling_Information.Fuel_Station_Zip, 
   First(Fueling_Information.Fuel_Address) AS [First Of Fuel_Address],
   Sum(Fueling_Information.Fuel_Price) AS [Sum Of Fuel_Price], 
   Sum(Fueling_Information.Fuel_Gallons_Truck) AS [Sum Of Fuel_Gallons_Truck], 
   Sum(Fueling_Information.Fuel_Gallons_DEF) AS [Sum Of Fuel_Gallons_DEF], 
   Sum(Fueling_Information.Fuel_Gallons_Reefer) AS [Sum Of Fuel_Gallons_Reefer], 
   Sum(Fueling_Information.Fuel_Total_Price) AS [Sum Of Fuel_Total_Price]
FROM Fueling_Information
GROUP BY 
  Fueling_Information.ID, 
  Fueling_Information.Fuel_Location_Name,   
  Fueling_Information.Fuel_Price_DEF,
  Format$([Fueling_Information].[Fuel_Date_Added],'mmmm yyyy'),
  Fueling_Information.Fuel_Truck_Number,
  Fueling_Information.Fuel_Trailer_Number,
  Fueling_Information.Fuel_City, 
  Fueling_Information.Fuel_State,
  Fueling_Information.Fuel_Station_Number,   
  Fueling_Information.Fuel_Station_Zip, 
  Year([Fueling_Information].[Fuel_Date_Added])*12+
    DatePart('m',[Fueling_Information].[Fuel_Date_Added])-1;
```

and where do I put  `"WHERE Truck_Number=102"`
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand all the requirements, but consider using sum with a case statement:

Comment: WHERE goes between FROM and GROUP BY.  Just an FYI, the basic structure and order of a SQL statement is SELECT, FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY.